# How to set javascript Date object in data- attributes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using google chart to draw a chart in my Rails project.

The data for chart are generated in a model.

#### Comapny#my_chart_data

```
def my_chart_data
  [
        ['date', 'value1', 'value2'],
        [Date.new(2017,1,11), 1, 2],
        [Date.new(2017,1,13), 3, 5],
        [Date.new(2017,1,16), 0, 7]
    ]
end
```

And in a view the method is called.

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "my-chart-data",
                data: {rows: company.my_chart_data} %>
```

Then the chart is created in the javascript.
Here I have to convert date string to a `Date` object, because the ruby `Date` instances are already converted to `String`.

```
function drawMarginBalance(type) {
    var array = $('#my-chart-data').data('rows');

    // convert date string to date object
    array = array.map(function (obj) {
        if (obj[0].match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)) {
            return [new Date(obj[0])].concat(obj.slice(1, 3));
        } else {
            return obj;
        }
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
    var options = {
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: {1: {type: 'line'}}
    };
    new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('my-chart')).draw(data, options);
}
```

The code works well as I expected. But I want to set a `Date` object (not `String`) in `data-` attributes.

How can I do it?

Comment: Not possible it will get converted to a string when setting it but if you use jQuerys data method it might still remain a object since jQuerys method doesn't write it to the dom but instead holds it in a internal object.

Comment: But it looks like that won't work for you since your not initially setting it with JavaScript but pre written server side.

Comment: Also your data attribute syntax is incorrect it needs to be data-your-attribute-name if you use anything other then jQuerys data method to read, it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Darkrum said, you cannot save anything other than a string inside of a data- attribute. Same thing for localStorage.  You should decide on a consistent format to use - either the time stamp or the full UTC String.
When you need to use the value later on pass the string or timestamp to a new Date( ) object and work with the resulting object.

Comment: I would recommend making all dates a epoch in milliseconds and using moment.js to manipulate and also their other library moment timezone if needing to handle time zones. Those libraries will save you a lot of hair tearing out because JavaScripts Date object just sucks that bad. I speak from experience having created a report system that handles dates for customers around the world.

Comment: I agree @Darkrum. moment is an excellent library http://momentjs.com/ and does save a lot of headaches when working with Dates in JS.